# How to make a keyboard button not get spammed in javascript. (Making a delay)

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I was working on Babylon.js when I wanted to make a jump. I found a website and copied  it jump code and it works perfectly! But I want to make a real game and I don't want people spamming spacebar to go flying. How could I make it have a few second delay so no one can keep on spamming spacebar and go flying?

```
function jump(){
  camera.cameraDirection.y = 2;
}

document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 32){
    //your code
    console.log("jump");
    setTimeout(jump(), 1000); 

  }
}
```

Link to my game

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#JCE1G3

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a persistent boolean variable such as `justJumped`, and only jump if `justJumped` is `false`. When jumping, set `justJumped` to true, and create a timeout that resets it back to `false` after the duration of the jump, which looks to be a bit less than half a second:

```
let justJumped = false;
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32 && !justJumped) {
    justJumped = true;
    setTimeout(() => justJumped = false, 400)
    console.log("jump");
    jump();
  }
}
```

Also note that `setTimeout(jump(), 1000);` probably isn't doing what you're thinking it does - it invokes `jump` *immediately*. If you wanted to call the `jump` function after 1000ms, just pass the *function name itself*:

```
let justJumped = false;
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32 && !justJumped) {
    justJumped = true;
    setTimeout(() => justJumped = false, 1400)
    console.log("jump");
    setTimeout(jump, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I now can slow down jumps to each second so no one can fly!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use other library to achieve it. My favorite one is `lodash`. You can use `_.throttle`

```
var throttled = _.throttle(jump, 1000);
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
       throttled()
    }
}
```

if you don't want to jump immediately after the first key up. you can add option `trailing: false`

```
var throttled = _.throttle(jump, 1000, { 'trailing': false });
```